# How increase hp enemy when he was instantiate

Tags: unity, c#

help, I can not understand. In my clicker game, when I click on an enemy, he dies. There is also a score counter here.Another code creates new monsters and immediately I try to increase their hp when the counter is 5. But it does not change the health of the created mobs through "

```csharp
public class OnEnemyClick : MonoBehaviour 
    [SerializeField] public float _fullHp = 5 ;

    void Update()
    {
         HealthBar();
    }
    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        _fullHp -= 5;
    }
    public void HealthBar()
    {
        if (_fullHp <= 0)
        {
            GameManager._updateScoreValue += 1;
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}

// GameManager.cs
public static int _updateScoreValue = 0;
int _arrayEnemiesIndex = (Random.Range(0, _arrayEnemies.Length));
Instantiate(_arrayEnemies[_arrayEnemiesIndex], GenerateSpawnPosition(), _arrayEnemies[_arrayEnemiesIndex].transform.rotation);
if(_updateScoreValue==5)
{
    onEnemyClick._fullHp += 20
}
```

Comment: We need the code for `SpawnManager` so we can see the full lifecycle of `onEnemyClick` and `_updateScoreValue`. Right now, my primary questions are is `_updateScoreValue` actually equal to `5`, and is `onEnemyClick` currently `null`?  Also, what is the difference between `GameManager` and `SpawnManager`? There are others, but that's where I'd start until we have more code to look at.

Comment: Hello, onEnemyclick I threw all. spawnmanager is gamemanager, I just thought there is no need to throw all the code.

Comment: How does the `onEnemyClick` variable get assigned? You have not shown us that. Try creating a new, empty project, and add just the bare minimum code you need to reproduce this problem. Then show us every line of code and every step of scene setup we'd need to follow to build that example in our own new empty project. This is what's called a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example.

Comment: I'm too dumb and apparently I started doing everything wrong..I have a field, enemies spawn on it. Enemies have hp equal to one click, when I click on them, they die. In the second script, the appearance of enemies is described. I do not understand what variable you are talking about, perhaps the one that I did not even create

Comment: `onEnemyClick._fullHp += 20` we are talking about this `onEnemyClick` variable. My guess is, what you probably need to do is store the GameObject from your Instantiate, access from there the ._fullHp via GetComponent<OnEnemyClick> and increase it afterwards. But instead of doing this each time, a better way might be to store the maxHp in your GameManager and on Start in your OnEnemyClick get it from there

Comment: You come to my aid again Zibelas.you understood my problem correctly.
I will try to do as you described, in the first way. In the second method, I don’t quite understand how to do it, because _fullHp is attached to the object and in this case, with one click, all other gameobjects are deleted

Comment: You missunderstood my second method. _fullHp stays on the OnEnemyClick script. In the OnStart() of OnEnemyClick, you would ask the GameManager what the current fullHp should be (5 at start and 25 afterwards). That way the logic stays on the GameManager.

Comment: you are a gold man, thank you again, the second method worked, i spent the whole day on this.I tried to do the first one, but it didn't work)probably did something wrong, but it doesn't matter

Comment: If you solved your problem, be sure to post the solution as an Answer below, or invite @Zibelas to post an answer you can mark "accepted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are two ways how to fix your problem.

The first is fixing it in the GameManager to set the hp correctly in the spawned enemy. This is a bit of guessing since we do not have the full GameManager. It is similar to your last question.

```
GameObject spawnedEnemy = Instantiate(_arrayEnemies[_arrayEnemiesIndex], GenerateSpawnPosition(), _arrayEnemies[_arrayEnemiesIndex].transform.rotation);
...
spawnedEnemy.GetComponent<OnEnemyClick>._fullHp += 20;
```

The second way is to have the GameManager hold the totalHp of the mop and the OnEnemyClick is grabbing that one at the start.

```
public class OnEnemyClick: MonoBehaviour {

   [SerializeField] public float _fullHp = 0;
   void Start() {
      _fullHp += GameManager.totalHp;
   }
   ...
}

GameManager.cs
public float totalHp = 5;
...
if(_updateScoreValue == 5) {
   totalHp += 20;
}
```

I personally prefer the second way, that way it is easier to make changes in one place. It would allow you to hold in one place hp if you decide that different enemies get different amount of hp for example.

Comment: I used the second method, only i got the variable via getcomponent. Thank you!

Comment: According to `GameManager._updateScoreValue += 1;` you have the ability to access variables directly (Singleton/ static). Keep it one way of access (either both directly or both via getcomponent). This will make it easier for you in case you do changes in the future and you don't have to find out again why some parts are not working anymore when you changed something else